# NSKeyedUnarchiver, how to decode securely the Any type

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have an array of dictionaries securely encoded into data files pre 10.13. Hopefully they can be decoded with the API changes to NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver in 10.13. Right now I am not able to decode securely a typed array [[String: Any]] in the newer API. Is there any way to do this?

```
// the older coding method, pre 10.14 . This works on 10.14.6
let arr: [[String: Any]] = [["one": "data"],["two": Double(2.0)]]
//let arr: [[String: String]] = [["one": "data"],["two": "data2"]]
let mutableData = NSMutableData()
let archiver: NSKeyedArchiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: mutableData)
archiver.requiresSecureCoding = true
archiver.encode(arr, forKey: "mydata")
archiver.finishEncoding()
let unarchiver = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: mutableData as Data)
let obj5 = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "mydata")
unarchiver.finishDecoding()
if (obj5 != nil) {
    let dataobj = obj5 as! [[String: Any]]
    print(dataobj)
}

// the newer coding method, 10.13+ . This gives obj6 as nil on 10.14.6
let archiver2 = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: true)
archiver2.encode(arr, forKey: "mydata")
let data = archiver2.encodedData
let unarchiver2 = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom: data)
unarchiver2.requiresSecureCoding = true
if unarchiver2.containsValue(forKey: "mydata") {
    let obj6 = unarchiver2.decodeObject(forKey: "mydata")
    //let obj6 = unarchiver2.decodeDecodable([[String: String]].self, forKey: "mydata")
    unarchiver2.finishDecoding()
    if (obj6 != nil) {
        let dataobj = obj6 as! [[String: Any]]
        print(dataobj)
    }
    else {
        print("nogood")
    }
}
else {
    print("phoey")
}
```

When executed in a playground on 10.14.6 this returns:

```
[["one": data], ["two": 2]]
nogood
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your second example is that you are not using secure decoding.

You don't actually need a key for this example, so let's simplify and just demonstrate how to do this with a root object:

```
do {
    let arr: [[String: Any]] = [["one": "data"],["two": Double(2.0)]]
    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(
        withRootObject: arr, requiringSecureCoding: true)
    if let output = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(
        ofClasses: [NSArray.self, NSDictionary.self], from: data)
        as? [[String:Any]] {
            print(output)
        } else {
            print("oops")
        }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

This *is* secure decoding, as the documentation on `unarchivedObject(ofClasses:from:)` makes clear.

For the sake of completeness, I'll just demonstrate the same thing using a key, more along the lines of your code:

```
do {
    let arr: [[String: Any]] = [["one": "data"],["two": Double(2.0)]]
    let arch = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: true)
    arch.requiresSecureCoding = true
    arch.encode(arr, forKey: "mydata")
    let data = arch.encodedData
    let unarch = try NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingFrom:data)
    if let output = try unarch.decodeTopLevelObject(
        of: [NSArray.self, NSDictionary.self], forKey: "mydata") 
        as? [[String:Any]] {
            print(output)
        } else {
            print("oops")
        }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: It was decodeTopLevelObject that I was missing, and how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it's tricky to discover because it is inherited from NSCoder.